# Drag-out Image from Browser to Desktop

Tags: javascript, css, html, browser, drag-and-drop

It's possible to drag an image from any browser to your desktop and have it automatically copied there. What I'd like to know is how to intercept this event and substitute a higher resolution version of the image to be copied instead. I've seen some "data-downloadurl" / "setData('DownloadURL', url)" based solution ideas (http://www.thecssninja.com/html5/gmail-dragout), but they are only successful in copying the url to the resource, not the actual resource. The default drag-n-drop operation on a browser actually copies the image to the desktop. This is what I want to do, only I want to control the resolution of the image that is actually copied.

Any ideas...?